# Finding the inverse of a matrix using elementary matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

This should be fairly simple as I know matrix A can be found by $$A = E_1^{-1} E_2^{-1}...E_k^{-1}$$
So it should go that $$A^-$$ can be found by $$E_kE_(k-1)...E_1$$

But for some reason my numbers aren't matching up with the book.

I have a matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0 &6&-1\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$

I find that I can get an Identity Matrix from this matrix by doing (1/6)R2 -> R2, (1/4)R3 -> R3, 1/6R3 + R2 -> R2, R3 + R1 -> R1. From there I can find the inverse of the elementary matrices no problem but for some reason my normal E does not multiply into the inverse. Did I do something wrong in my steps? 
It should be noted I need to solve the matrix using elementary matrices.

Comment: Also can anyone tell me how to properly make _ and ^ work for more than just the next thing I type? I'm having trouble figuring out why it doesn't work as seen in my examples above; I am sorry for the inconvenience/eyesore.

Comment: Use "{}" to wrap all of your $-1$, e.g. $A^{-1}$ vs $A^-1$. Same for "E_{k-1}" as in $E_{k-1}$ v.s. $E_k-1$.

Comment: It’s very hard to say what you did wrong if you don’t show the details of your steps. It might be something as simple as multiplying the elementary matrices together in the wrong order.

Comment: Is... Is that really a worry? If I multiply the E's in wrong order can that really ruin the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E_1\cdots E_n A = I$, then $A^{-1} = E_1\cdots E_n I$.

So you can transform $A$ into $I$ and simultaneously transform $I$ to $A^{-1}$ using the same transformations:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1&0&-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 &6&-1& 0 & 1 & 0\\0&0&4& 0 & 0& 1
  \end{array}\right]
 \sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1&0&-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 &1&-\frac16& 0 & \frac16 & 0\\0&0&1& 0 & 0& \frac14
  \end{array}\right]\sim \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1&0&0 & 1 & 0 & \frac14\\0 &1&0& 0 & \frac16 & \frac1{24}\\0&0&1& 0 & 0& \frac14
  \end{array}\right]$$

so $A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac14 \\ 0 & \frac16 & \frac1{24} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac14\end{bmatrix}$.

---

Using elementary matrices with [this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix), our transformations are $$L_{3,2}\left(\frac16\right)L_{3,1}(1)D_3\left(\frac14\right)D_2\left(\frac16\right)A = I$$

so \begin{align}
A^{-1} &= L_{3,2}\left(\frac16\right)L_{3,1}(1)D_3\left(\frac14\right)D_2\left(\frac16\right)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac16 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac14 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac16 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac14 \\ 0 & \frac16 & \frac1{24} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac14\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: Forgot I could do this; thank you for reminding me of the augmented matrices role

Comment: just remembered why I didn't do the augmented matrix method; I was suppose to solve by using elementary matrices. Do you know how to do that @mechanodroid?

Comment: @Charlatan Sure, have a look now.

Comment: Not sure how to read this notation; would you mind explaining what D and L mean? I have the same values you got for the elementary matrices I noticed but I ordered mine backwards from yours; am I suppose to put $$E_1$$ as the first transformation?

Comment: @Charlatan The notation is explained in the linked page. $D_i(\lambda)$ is a matrix which multiplies row $i$ by a scalar $\lambda$. $L_{i,j}(\lambda)$ is a matrix which  adds row $i$ multiplied by $\lambda$ to row $j$.

Comment: You can also write $$A = D_2\left(\frac16\right)^{-1}D_3\left(\frac14\right)^{-1}L_{3,1}(1)^{-1}L_{3,2}\left(\frac16\right)^{-1}$$
like you first did so the order is reversed, but notice that the matrices are inverted too.